# Powershell Sting Manipulation

Tags: string, powershell, cut

I need to get few object from the output in a particular format mention after the output. Below is my output:

```
CompanyId        : 5d120af63e34a656bb6xxxxx
MachineId        : 5db2a769a43b9c68875xxxxx
UserId           : 5d120ac73e34a656bb6xxxxx
OwnerId          : 5d120ac73e34a656bb6xxxxx
Version          : 1.0.7
InstallationType : Regular
HttpsProxy       :
Socks5Proxy      :
NodeId           : A32BDF0D57F72509B2F7D208A106D2F92AC469AAD5BA8630C8198Dxxxxxxxxxx
Environment      : try
PSPath           : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apptinuum\SupportBOT
PSParentPath     : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apptinuum
PSChildName      : SupportBOT
PSDrive          : HKLM
PSProvider       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

This is my output
I want to manipulate object in following format:

```
CompanyId/MachineId/NodeId
```

only:

```
5d120af63e34a656bb6xxxxx/5db2a769a43b9c68875xxxxx/A32BDF0D57F72509B2F7D208A106D2F92AC469AAD5BA8630C8198Dxxxxxxxxxx
```

How can I get object like this using Powershell?

Comment: Assuming you already have an object with the properties listed here, you can do `$object.companyid,$object.machineid,$object.nodeid -join '/'`.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use -f (-format):

```
"{0}/{1}/{2}" -f $yourobject.CompanyId , $yourobject.MachineId , $yourobject.NodeId
```